# Get an array of values of a field in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some entries like:

```
{ "name":"a", "value":10 }
{ "name":"b", "value":20 }
{ "name":"c", "value":10 }
...
```

And I can select names from a query with `db.collection.find({"value":10},{"name":1, _id: false})`. It gives me the following:

```
{ "name" : "a" }
{ "name" : "c" }
...
```

However, I want it to return an array of values, not a set of { key : value } pairs. (like `[ "a", "c", ... ]`). Is there a way to achieve this with only `MongoDB` queries or should I select and put them in an array in my application?

Current Output:

```
{ "name" : "a" }
{ "name" : "c" }
...
```

Expected output:

```
["a", "c", ...]
```

If the above is not a possible output, it may be also

```
{ "result": ["a", "c", ...] }
```

Comment: Use **[$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)**

Comment: But how? Where to put it in this query?

Comment: It's still confusing, can you add your expected output

Comment: You can try db.collection.distinct( "name", { "value": 10 })

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db.collection.distinct( "name", { "value": 10 })
```

from *@Sagar Reddy* comment will return a *set array*:

```
["a", "c"]
```

This is probably what you need. Aniway, a similar more complex query can be achieved using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), where you can use extra aggregation stages.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { value: 10 }},
    { $group: { _id: null, result: { $addToSet: '$name' }}}, 
    { $project: { _id: 0, result: 1 }}
])
```

In the `group` stage, `addToSet` can be replaced with `push` if you want the same value to appear multiple times.

Output using `addToSet`:

```
{ "result" : [ "c", "a" ] }
```

Ex output using `push`:

```
{ "result" : [ "a", "c", "c" ] }
```

Comment: The output of this query gives `{ "result" : [ { "result" : [ "c", "b" ] } ], "ok" : 1 }`. How can I make it just `{ "result" : [ "c", "b" ]  }`?

Comment: It is extra aggregation output information, you will *always* get that in return from your driver, that is the first `result` key which holds the aggregation result. The second `result` key which holds the array is the key that you define in the aggregation stages.  Just acces the key inside the dict: `actualResult` = `aggregationResult['result']`